# Clear the misunderstanding regarding this situation

Tags: team, manager, team-role, seniority

So I'm a new developer who joined recently in a reputed company. I've joined a small team with some other people.

I'm learning from them and generally consult them, especially if I need any clarifications regarding anything related to work. Recently, I was chatting with them and asked clarification about a company policy regarding a certain matter. They gave me a certain opinion on it and I was all for it. I still thought I could use some clarification regarding it so I went to our manager (the person heading multiple teams) with my question. **Mistake 1**

I asked them for some clarity on the matter and requested if they could make a general announcement regarding the same (since the matter was relevant to many teams and generally unspoken of, I thought it would be beneficial to all of them).  **Mistake 2**.

Now the manager, intentionally or unintentionally seems to made the announcement in a way that  seemed to me to be similar to my situation. I dont think he did this intentionally, he may have been  looking out for everyone's best interests. I think he also made that clarification as a general one applying to everyone present.

Now I think it was a mistake on two parts as highlighted in the text before:

1.) I went for an outside opinion even though they were senior devops, those guys seriously know what they're doing

2.) I should've just spoken to the manager with all the devops being present as this should've avoided any confusions on who said what.

3.) I should've just kept my mouth shut and followed the guys who've been there longer

Is there any way to salvage this? Am I missing something or not being able to see something in the situation?

**EDIT:**

I think the manager may have been addressing everyone under him and did not mean any harm. He may only have been trying to make sure that everyone under him gets an opportunity to do their work in a safe environment while at the same time making sure that they keep everyone happy.

I think if anyone came across this after going through the same, then the best course of action is learn from my mistakes outlined above and dont disturb your manager unless really needed.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea what you are talking about. Can't you give more specific examples? The X,Y examples along with the phrasing makes the post very unclear IMO

Comment: At this point I dont care if you close my question (as this will be eventually) because I already have a good (accepted) answer below.

Comment: The reason people want you to improve your question is so that others can benefit from it. This is a community, please try to engage with it rather than just sucking answers out. By the way, if you did seek to improve the question, maybe someone would give you an even better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create waves, you get waves.

As a recent hire you should just keep your head down, stay within your team without getting into anything controversial such as questioning company policies and asking managers to make announcements.

Gain some experience and prove your worth before doing anything apart from focusing on your tasks. Look, learn, ask people around you.

> I still want to know why they did it

There is no way to tell, probably unhappy about being asked to announce, but it's not constructive to keep going down that path, work on mitigating the end result instead.

> Steps I could take to salvage

Not many proactive ones you can take. Probably best just to live it down quietly and if asked or hassled, shrug and say something like 'I didn't mean it the way it came out.' Eventually so long as you don't get controversial again for a while it will all disappear.